# Background image not displaying properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, background

Im using an svg as background for my html site. It works fine on most Desktops and a few broswers like Chrome on android, but in other browsers, there is this weird white blank area beneath the image. Any idea why this is happening? Here's what I mean - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHqDK.jpg

This is my styling right now. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
html {
    background: url('Bubble.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

It works completely fine on Chrome, but is offset to the right and bottom on firefox mobile, and is not displaying properly on edge mobile too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 100% 100% instead of center center.
I would suggest to add the background image to a container in body rather to the html. Wrap your contents in a div and add image to that.

```css
.bgImg{
background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg') 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImg">
 
</div>
```